# How to extract specific text with imacros xpath

Tags: html, xpath, html-lists, imacros

I have this code in a website:

```
<div id="1234">
<li>
text I want to extract
<span>
text I don't want to extract
</span>
</li>
</div>
```

I'm using this IMACROS code, but it extracts both texts:

```
TAG XPATH="id('1234')/li[1]" EXTRACT=TXT
```

I was trying to use text() at the end but get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your **Specific case** Shugar's code with some tweaking will work. Split `\n` and extract `[1]` :

```
TAG XPATH="id('1234')/li[1]" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.split('\\n')[1];")
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

If you want a more **General approach** you can get `li[1]` and split by content of `span`  at `[0]`:

```
TAG XPATH="id('1234')/li[1]" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL 
TAG XPATH="id('1234')/li[1]/span" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!VAR1}}'.split('{{!EXTRACT}}')[0];")
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just adding one more line in your code:

```
TAG XPATH="id('1234')/li[1]" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.split('<span>')[0];")
```

Comment: this would work if the extracted text would contain <span> in it, however it only brings up:  text I want to extracttext I don't want to extract

Comment: You're right! That was my fault. (In such cases I prefer to use `EXTRACT=HTM`.)