# How to access HTML DOM Property using iMacros - xPath

Tags: javascript, xpath, web-scraping, macros, imacros

iMacros ver: 10.0.2.1450 (FREE), Firefox, WIndow 10

Hello,
The objective is to extract the value of HTML DOM Property such as id,href and data-download-file-url for each of the images displayed from this [website](https://www.freepik.com/search?dates=any&format=search&page=1&query=Polygonal%20Human&sort=popular). I believe XPATH will be suitable for this task as each of the image can be accessed by the following generalise XPATH

```
/html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/figure[X]/div
```

with the capital **X** indicate the Image label that take the value from 1 to 50, for the aforementioned website.

I know that, to extract the properties of Figure 1, for example, can be achieved by

```
TAG XPATH="/html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/figure[1]"  EXTRACT=TXT
```

However, the line above outputted all DOM Property including the one that I am not interested with.

According to the tutorial  below;

[OP1][https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?t=26155]
[OP2][[How to extract specific text with imacros xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540244/how-to-extract-specific-text-with-imacros-xpath])

Extracting specific DOM property can be achieved by something like the following

```
TAG XPATH="/html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/figure[1]/div[@id='showcase__content'] "  EXTRACT=TXT
```

However, the execution instead give an error.

I really appreciate if someone can shed some light about this problem.

Example of the DOM property for Figure 1. The properties are all in pink color.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=190q615C3uXLZUQNI8K4AJYL3Slii1ktO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath contains an error (@id instead of @class). Fix it with :

```
//figure[1]/div[@class='showcase__content']
```

To access the url for downloading the file, it would be :

```
//figure[1]/div[@class='showcase__content']//@data-download-file-url
```

EDIT : To get values from specific attributes you have to extract the code from the element with the HTM function and then use regex. HREF attributes can be extracted directly.

I'm not an imacros user, so my code might not be the smartest :

```
VERSION BUILD=1005 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://www.freepik.com/search?dates=any&format=search&page=1&query=Polygonal%20Human&sort=popular
TAG XPATH="//figure[1]/div[@class='showcase__content']/a" EXTRACT=HREF
SET !VAR3 {{!EXTRACT}}
TAG XPATH="//figure[1]/div[@class='showcase__content']/a" EXTRACT=HTM
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var regex = /url=\"(.+?)\"/; var str = '{{!EXTRACT}}';str.match(regex)[1];")
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var regex = /id=\"(.+?)\"/; var str = '{{!EXTRACT}}';str.match(regex)[1];")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
PROMPT {{!VAR2}}
PROMPT {{!VAR3}}
```

Side notes : free users of imacros are limited to 3 declared variables (!VAR1 to 3). You might need loops and SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO to achieve your final goal.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @e.wiest.

I tried your proposed recommendation, but it produce an error of #EANF#. FYI, I had tried both with the double and single slash (i.e., // and /). Appreciate for any hints

Comment: To add my previous comment:
Your second proposal produce error

TypeError: element.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Comment: OK. I figured it out. I've posted a sample of code.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you. I will refine the code and share it later

Comment: '+1' from me also for this Answer @E.Wiest, is nearly "too smart" actually, ah-ah...! Compliment...! - I posted some Comment/Feedback in #OP's parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum...: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=30959&p=85146#p85146